# Where's the best place to call Python's multiprocessing function?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've written a script that simulates a series of biochemical reactions over time and plots the results of changing molecules numbers on a graph. I now need to start parallelising the script starting with running multiple simulations at once. I've read pythons `multiprocessing` documentation and got the following code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
with Pool() as Pool:   
    result = Pool.apply_async(gillespie_tau_leaping, [propensity_calc, popul_num, LHS, stoch_rate, popul_num_all, tao_all, rxn_vector, tao, epsi])  
    print(result.get(timeout=1))
```

At the moment this is at the end of my script.

The function that I'm trying to parallelise is `gillespie_tau_leaping` which is mainly a large `while` loop that simulates as long as the current time is below a certain threshhold and updates input arrays such as `popul_num` with molecule numbers after a specific reaction has fired.

I don't know where abouts to put the above parallelisation code, when its at the end of my script it doesn't really work because it simulates everything once, reaches the parallelisation then simulates it all again in parallel. But if I put it at the start I'm referencing the function before I've defined it.

Should I leave it at the end or is there something else I can do to simulate it in parallel at the beginning?

Any suggestions ?

Cheers

Comment: As a general statement, parallelism works well when several pieces of the computation can be done in an independent manner. That is, part A does not depend on the results of calculation B. Do you have such a thing in your case?

Comment: No, at the moment I'm just trying to simulate the whole script, which contains functions which are dependent on each other, multiple times in parallel